# Canvas Game Space Bar Scrolls Browser

Tags: javascript, canvas, keyboard-events

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
   myHandleKeyboardEvent(event);
}, false);
```

This works fine for me. The events are sent to my handler.

But whenever I hit the space bar, the browser window scrolls.

Is there some way to swallow keyboard events before they get to the browser?

(I've tried putting the handler on the `window` and the `document` with the same results).

Comment: you can attach the event handler to document and use event.preventDefault()

Comment: that worked first time. I searched everywhere and that answer didn't show up anywhere. Thanks much!

Comment: Though, you might want to make your canvas focusable (by adding a tabindex attribute to it) and only prevent the default behavior of keydown when your canvas is the document.activeElement, to avoid blocking it when it's not needed.

Comment: @Kaiido - Yes. That's good advice. I've also had to set the canvas's tabIndex=1 or it wont attract the focus. Thanks gents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it worked I am posting it as the answer:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
document.addEventListener(
  "keydown",
  function(event) {
    if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement.id === canvas.id) {
      event.preventDefault();
      myHandleKeyboardEvent(event);
    }
  },
  false
);
```

Snippet now includes important suggestion given by [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido)
This is a link to the working demo. https://codesandbox.io/s/o714xx10nz